# ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/a/Desktop/a

Tags: iphone

When building an  app that uses the Core Plot framework, I am seeing the following linker errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/a/Desktop/a
7-31-12 10.57 AM/usr/local/lib/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, missing
required architecture i386 in file
/Users/a/Desktop/a 7-31-12 10.57
AM/usr/local/lib/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a (2 slices) Undefined symbols
for architecture i386:   "_CPTDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
       -[CPTTestAppScatterPlotController viewDidLoad] in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       -[CPTTestAppScatterPlotController changePlotRange] in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       -[StatsVC CallBarChart] in StatsVC.o   "_CPTDecimalFromInt", referenced from:
       -[StatsVC CallBarChart] in StatsVC.o
       -[StatsVC CallScatterChart] in StatsVC.o   "_CPTDecimalFromString", referenced from:
       -[CPTTestAppScatterPlotController viewDidLoad] in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       -[StatsVC CallBarChart] in StatsVC.o
       -[StatsVC CallScatterChart] in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTAxisLabel", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTBarPlot", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTColor", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTConstraints", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTFill", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGradient", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableLineStyle", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotRange", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotSymbol", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTScatterPlot", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTextStyle", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTheme", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       objc-class-ref in StatsVC.o   "_kCPTDarkGradientTheme", referenced from:
       -[CPTTestAppScatterPlotController viewDidLoad] in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       -[StatsVC CallScatterChart] in StatsVC.o
       -[CPTTestAppScatterPlotController viewDidLoad] in CPTTestAppScatterPlotController.o
       -[StatsVC CallScatterChart] in StatsVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
 code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried linking coreplot properly, changed architecture to armv6,armv7 etc...but facing this issue since 3 days

Any suggestion what is the issue here?

Comment: Here some things to try: clean all targets; make sure you have the right developer profile/sdk/device/target; try another path for CorePlot lib; check file inspector target membership; add the library in project target settings -> build phases; even "validate settings" may work

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Coreplot has been built to run on the device (ie arm6/7 architecture) and you're trying to compile for i386, likely the Simulator? Try compiling Coreplot for i386 as well.

For the /Users/a/Desktop/a problem, perhaps you've included that file erroneously in your linking phase? Go into your project settings, then "Build phases", finally look under "Link binary with libraries".

Comment: You're gonna have to be more specific. I suggested two things.

Answer (score 1):

I run through same issue this is how i solved.

Step 1. 
         Right Click at your Folder-->Add Files to "ProjectName"--> 
         make sure to select copy files to the same project.

Step 2.    Now Go to   Targets-->Build Phases-->  Link Binary With Libraries
            here you will see    binary files added for that specific 3rd party library such as 
            For CorePlot  libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a but it is not linked properly normally it is
            copied into same Directory when you used  (Add Files To "Your ProjectName") but these 
            are not linked properly so delete it by selecting and using  (-) symbol. Now use (+) 
            symbol to add it again binary  such as in the case of   CorePlot use
            libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

So build your project and you are done.   In my case this helped me to solve my issue.

However  there are always issues due to  64 bit and 32 bit architectures,you can study here in the documentation  [apple documentation on settings related to 64/32 bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/CocoaTouch64BitGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

Xcode 4.6

first

TARGETS>Build Phases>Target Dependencies: add "CorePlot-CocoaTouch"

second

Link Binary With Libraries: add "libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a"